# files not visible on my seagate expnsion drive

Tags: data-loss

i am using a 1 TB expansion drive and it has 643.6 GB data used as the properties window says, but there is a folder in there is around 500 GB data which i can not see. It's properties are showing contents : nothing.

Now when i am connecting the drive a message appears saying

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/gurmeet/Seagate Expansion Drive: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/gurmeet/Seagate Expansion Drive"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Please help...

Comment: What is the name of the file.Can you delete it?

Comment: its not a file it's folder named MOVIES (:p) which lots data whiich i can't see.

Comment: Why not just delete it?

Comment: But i don't want to  delete it i want access the videos in it.

Comment: do you have permission to read the contents?

Comment: yes, infact i was able to see the contents yesterday but later when i tried to access them it is showing nothing. But 1 thing is sure that data not deleted and it is still there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13147/discussion-between-aditya-patil-and-gurmeet)